# Pointing multiple subdomains at the same WordPress Installation

Tags: multisite, customization, subdomains

We have some branded subdomains for clients in our application.  so client.ourdomain.com gets some minor customization to the look and feel.  We are now creating some marketing pages and implementing WordPress as a CMS but we want to be able to keep the branding per subdomain.

Basically we want client1.ourdomain.com to point to the same installation as www.ourdomain.com but the menus at least need to point to client1.ourdomain.com.  The same would be true for client2.ourdomain.com, etc.  The list of branded subdomains is a fixed list and approximately 20.

Comment: If your question is "Can WordPress Multisite do this?", then the answer is almost certainly "Yes".  If you haven't read it already, read [Create A Network](http://codex.wordpress.org/Create_A_Network) and the equally-important [Before You Create a Network](http://codex.wordpress.org/Before_You_Create_A_Network) thoroughly.

Comment: On the Before You Create a Network page is specifically says:
"if you plan on creating sites that are strongly interconnected, **that share data**, or share users, then a multisite network might **not** be the best solution."

So I assumed Multisite wouldn't be the solution for this.

Comment: "Might not".  I'm using Multisite to run a university website with ~100 sites.  Some users are editors on multiple sites.  All my news comes from a central source -- shared data. It sort of depends on how much data you need to share, and what kind.